# Inserting data in to a 2 dimensional byte[] array

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading

I am new to Java and trying to use a two dimensional **byte[ ]** type. I have created a 2D `byte[]` array as shown bellow. But whenever I try to insert some data to it, it gives an error saying: `NullPointerException`

```
    byte[][][] Requisition = new byte[10][][];
    byte[] someinput = ("example").getBytes();
    Requisition[0][0]=someinput;
    System.out.println("Printing:" + Requisition[0][0].toString());
    etc..
```

Data type I am inserting in to this 2D array is type `byte[]`  . Because what I am inserting is an encrypted data, these data will have the format of **byte[ ]** , not **byte**

I want `Requisition` array to hold two inputs for one line. For example

```
Requisition[0][1]=someinput1;
Requisition[0][2]=someinput2;
```

This `someinput1` I am wanting to insert is not type `byte`. Data I am inserting will be `byte[]` type.

What I mean byte[] is (sequence of bytes using the platform's default charset, storing the result into a new byte array.)

Comment: Try some thing like this: byte[][] Requisition = new byte[2][some int];

Comment: byte[][][] Requisition = new byte[2][][]; is not a 2D array it is 3D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
byte[][][] someinput = new byte[5][5][5];
```

Then you can insert data in to this array.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `arr[n][m]` you're accessing an element of whatever type `arr` is. In your case this is a `byte`. If you want to assign an array to a 2D array simply do:

```
Requisition[0] = someinput;
```

And...

```
    byte[][] Requisition = new byte[10][];
    byte[] someinput = ("example").getBytes();
    Requisition[0]=someinput;//These insertion will happens in a loop later
```

tested with...

```
    for (byte b : Requisition[0])
        System.out.println(b);
```

Of course, this answer is based on the fact you're not actually dealing with a 2D array, you have a 3D array which is likely a result of erroneous insertions of an array into a single element. If not, apply this logic to any *n* dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

No, you didn't create a two dimension array. You created a three dimension array! -> `byte[1][2][3]`

If you want create a two dimension array, you need to declare the columns and cells of your table. That's only two values, not three like you did. For clarity look at this picture: http://www.php-kurs.info/grafik/xyz.png

A two dimension array you can declare and fill like that:

```
int rows = 10;
int cols = 10;
int[][] twoDimension = new int[rows][cols];

for (int i = 0; i < twoDimension.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < twoDimension[i].length; j++) {
        twoDimension[i][j] = // Value you want to fill!
    }
}
```

That's an array of int values. If you want create a byte array, you need to change the declaration of the array.

```
byte[][] twoDimension = new byte[rows][cols];
```